# Excel VLOOKUP w/ SUM function

Tags: excel

I was wondering if it is possible to combine VLOOKUP with SUM function in Excel. I'm stuck now for awhile, here's my recent code:

```
=IF(COUNTIF('Supplies IN'!A3:A23,"MOSQUITO NET")>1,SUM(VLOOKUP("MOSQUITO NET",Table1,12,FALSE)))
```

However, it does not work.

What I would like to happen is that, on my "Supplies IN" sheet, I would like to get all the records for my "Mosquito net" and then add all their quantity. What's happening now is that the result only shows the first match it can find.

This is what I would like to happen:

```
ROW1: Mosquito net 500pcs
ROW2: Mosquito net 200pcs
```

Result (on a different Sheet): Mosquito net 800pcs

Hope someone can guide me on the right direction.

Thank you!

Comment: Did you mean that your result should be 700 (and not 800)? Also, Google for Excel function `SUMIF`.

Comment: @FDavidov, yes 700, sorry for mistyping that. And Thank you! Figured it out with SUMIF function :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this formula
`=SUMIF('Supplies IN'!A3:A23,"Mosquito Net",B3:B23)`